# Error when running updates on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, plesk

I get the following error when running dpkg update via the command line on my Ubuntu server and have no idea how to resolve it

```
2019-02-03 06:25:32 INFO: no packages to update
E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
2019-02-03 06:26:01 ERROR: installArchives() failed
2019-02-03 06:26:01 ERROR: Exited with returncode 1.
```

When running dpkg -l I see the following bad packages

```
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic      4.15.0-42.45                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic      4.15.0-43.46                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  linux-image-4.15.0-44-generic      4.15.0-44.47                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic      4.15.0-45.48                                amd64        Signed kernel image generic
```

I am running a Plesk server on Ubuntu 18.04 if this is useful

---

**df Results**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            478M     0  478M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M  716K   98M   1% /run
/dev/vda1        25G  7.2G   17G  30% /
tmpfs           493M  8.0K  493M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/sda         25G   14G   11G  57% /mnt/volume_sfo2_01
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/0
```

---

*Remove Packages*

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic
 linux-image-4.15.0-44-generic
 linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic
```

---

**Audit Output**

```
# sudo dpkg --audit linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic
The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic Signed kernel image generic
```

---

**Purge Output**

```
# sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic:
 linux-image-virtual depends on linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic
```

---

Below is the post install script. I have checked the directories mentioned and they all exist however some of the modules listed are missing as you can see with the ls near the bottom

```
cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic.postrm
#!/bin/sh
set -e

version=4.15.0-45-generic
image_path=/boot/vmlinuz-$version

rm -f /lib/modules/$version/.fresh-install

if [ "$1" != upgrade ] && command -v linux-update-symlinks >/dev/null; then
    linux-update-symlinks remove $version $image_path
fi

if [ -d /etc/kernel/postrm.d ]; then
    # We cannot trigger ourselves as at the end of this we will no longer
    # exist and can no longer respond to the trigger.  The trigger would
    # then become lost.  Therefore we clear any pending trigger and apply
    # postrm directly.
    if [ -f /usr/lib/linux/triggers/$version ]; then
    echo "$0 ... removing pending trigger"
    rm -f /usr/lib/linux/triggers/$version
    rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty /usr/lib/linux/triggers
    fi
    DEB_MAINT_PARAMS="$*" run-parts --report --exit-on-error --arg=$version \
          --arg=$image_path /etc/kernel/postrm.d
fi

if [ "$1" = purge ]; then
    for extra_file in modules.dep modules.isapnpmap modules.pcimap \
                      modules.usbmap modules.parportmap \
                      modules.generic_string modules.ieee1394map \
                      modules.ieee1394map modules.pnpbiosmap \
                      modules.alias modules.ccwmap modules.inputmap \
                      modules.symbols modules.ofmap \
                      modules.seriomap modules.\*.bin \
              modules.softdep modules.devname; do
    eval rm -f /lib/modules/$version/$extra_file
    done
    rmdir /lib/modules/$version || true
fi

exit 0
root@serv1:~# cd /lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic
root@serv1:/lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic# ls
build          modules.alias.bin    modules.dep.bin  modules.symbols
initrd         modules.builtin      modules.devname  modules.symbols.bin
kernel         modules.builtin.bin  modules.order    vdso
modules.alias  modules.dep          modules.softdep
root@serv1:/lib/modules/4.15.0-45-generic#
```

Answer (score 2):

The "F" in the second column of the dpkg list says "Half configured". A common cause for that is "too little disk space".

Check the output of:
`sudo df -h | grep -v loop`
... and look for high usage percentages.

I'd also try to remove the half configured packages, in one go that is:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic linux-image-4.15.0-44-generic linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic
```

Keep an eye open for any removal stopping errors occurs, include them above if so, then re-check with `df` above to see if the situation changed.

*Whether anything more needs to be done depends on your findings.
You need to append relevant NEW info in your original posting. Click `edit` and then type a `<hr>` at the end, and paste the new info after it.*

---

Next step if the above doesn't help:
`sudo dpkg --audit linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic`
... and add the output in the same manner as above.

Based on the result, the following step might be:
`sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic`
... with the same repeated for each of the remaining troublesome packages.

---

As we see:
"... linux-image-virtual depends on linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic."
try:
`sudo apt-get purge linux-image-virtual linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic`

---

Same error still: Well then, try stepping up the removal attempts a bit, by using the -f (fix) flag:
`sudo apt-get -f purge linux-image-virtual`
`sudo apt-get -f purge linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic`

if that doesn't work, then try a bit harder with the "lower level" dpkg:
`sudo dpkg --remove linux-image-virtual`
`sudo dpkg --remove linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic`

Repeat for the other error-packages if any of it might give an actual cleanup.

And evidently, if one of these is **in use; and actually works**; that package would not be one to attempt removal on.

Additionally, by checking where the post removal scripts actually live (apparently they're not listed as part of the packages) with `locate` I came up with this:

`cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic.postrm`

... read through that script and check your file system, whether there are folders mentioned in the script that are missing or if there are other odd things that might trigger a failure.

---

**GENERAL INFO: Dealing with kernel-related packages**
`uname -r`  # this prints the currently ACTIVE kernel name; cannot be removed!

`sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic` # removes a kernel

`sudo update-initramfs -u` # remakes boot ramdisk
`sudo update-grub2`  # re-creates boot menu
*The last two are essential to restore the boot menu and make the entries actually work at next reboot.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply

I have checked with df as your suggested and I have 7.2GB left on the main drive and after running apt-get purge this did not change the situation.

Comment: I have run both your commands and updated above. I ran this for both ***.43 and ****.45 wit no difference in the output apart for the version numbers

Comment: Did you get things sorted, what did you do to achieve that? Was the above helpful in the process?

Comment: Hi I am try trying these now. I can't run these during the week as the server is used for developing WP sites on. I will let you know if anything works

Comment: I am running kernel 44 so never tried that one but I am getting the same failed post-remove script error on both 43 and 45 with the above commands.

Comment: Running out of ideas... added a couple things to try, and checking the "post removal script".

Comment: Yes, this is becoming a pain. 

I have updated this with a copy of the post removal script and a view of one of the directories. Could missing modules be the cause?